# Add Homepage link to Magento menu bar

Tags: magento

I am trying to add a homepage link to the main menu of Magento. I have modified top.phtml in my template/catalog/navigation and added the line

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></a>
</li>
```

between the `<ul>`'s but it doesn't work?

Comment: There's a semicolon missing after `$this->getUrl('')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<li>
      <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></a>
</li>
```

Then flush cache if any

Comment: Turn on developer mode, you maybe using the wrong template or cache issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. It will return the base url of your site.

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>
```